# installing rgl, PKI, and stringi with an error with C compiler

Tags: r, macos

I am having an issue installing following R packages, rgl, PKI and stringl.  I got the following out put (e.g. rgl);

> All my packages loaded Sat Sep  2 22:28:57 2017
>   * installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
>   ** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   checking for gcc... /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp
>   checking whether the C compiler works... no

I am using;

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0 (64-bit)

R studio Version 1.0.15

OSX 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.6
BuildVersion:   16G29

gcc (Homebrew GCC 7.2.0) 7.2.0

Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b) (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Issue resolved by removing R Makevars file.